# Where we can get Adobe® Stratus 2 examples on "Swarming", Live Application-Level Multicast, Distributed Data Storage?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml, soundcloud-stratus

When and where will see (ore already can get) Adobe® Stratus 2 examples (with source) on "Swarming", Live Application-Level Multicast, Distributed Data Storage? 
[image]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://superior0.narod.ru/StratusP2P.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this topic. 
[Here are **official Adobe Answers**](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2542150#2542150).